# Android: Device Admin: Start Device Admin From Service

Tags: android, device-admin

I am unable to get the Activity which allows the user to grant permission for an app to be a device admin to work.

My code is as follows...

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(this, CustomReceiver.class);

Intent i = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);

i.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, comp);
i.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Explanation");

startActivity(i);
```

The application does not crash / report an exception. What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: A little late but...You need to use startActivityForResult() as nitinreddy suggested but you cannot do that from a service. To do so from a service, the best thing to do would be start a transparent activity, request admin rights from that activity, and then finish() that activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17297711/581159 this may help you...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do

```
if (!mPolicy.isAdminActive()) {

    Intent activateDeviceAdminIntent =
        new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);

    activateDeviceAdminIntent.putExtra(
        DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
        mPolicy.getPolicyAdmin());

    // It is good practice to include the optional explanation text to
    // explain to user why the application is requesting to be a device
    // administrator. The system will display this message on the activation
    // screen.
    activateDeviceAdminIntent.putExtra(
        DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
        getResources().getString(R.string.device_admin_activation_message));

    startActivityForResult(activateDeviceAdminIntent,
        REQ_ACTIVATE_DEVICE_ADMIN);
}
```

May be you are not considering

```
mPolicy.getPolicyAdmin()
```

Comment: Hi first of all thanks a lot for the response. What is "getPolicyAdmin" a member of ? I can't seem to find it to be a method of DevicePolicyManager ?

Comment: No, is CustomReceiver the Component which references deviceadmin class?

Comment: Meaning the one which extends DeviceAdminReceiver ? would you mind sharing that bit of code with me ? Just editing the above answer would do.

Comment: Sure, I will just look into the sample I have, but you should be able to figure it out from here if you didn't check the link. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clear example on how to do it, (the official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/work/device-management-policy.html#ActivateDeviceAdmin) miss some context)

```
//class that implements DeviceAdminReceiver, defined in the Manifest 
ComponentName deviceAdminCN = new ComponentName(context, DeviceAdminReceiverImpl.class) 

...

Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, deviceAdminCN);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "your explanation for the user here");
startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
```

[Here is the reference class used in the official sample app.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/b9c12ba27b639e8a932c1772cf3e50d699e1baac/samples/training/device-management-policy/src/com/example/training/deviceadmin/Policy.java)