# How to run Device Police Manager From A Service

Tags: android, android-service, device-policy-manager

I am able to create an Activity that uses the DevicePolicyManager API's.

The tutorials show that I need use it the following fashion:

```
     if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
    intent.putExtra("wipe-data", DeviceAdminInfo.USES_POLICY_WIPE_DATA);        
   startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE);

} 
else {

mDPM.wipeData(0);

}
```

However I would like this to run inside a Service. 
But I cant call

```
startActivityForResult
```

from within a Service.

So what would be the best approach or strategy for me to try ?

Comment: Either `enable device admin` from user interface or use `startActivity`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17297711/581159 this may help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason you need to call `startActivityForResult()` is if your app is not presently configured as a device administrator, to lead the user to go set that up for you. Hence, put that portion of your logic inside of your user interface.

Your service itself would just skip doing anything if `isAdminActive()` returns `false`.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare guy !